# Strip HTML from trimmed body before it is trimmed

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

Teaser display has been set to display "summary or trimmed" at 200 characters but the auto generated trimmed body comes through with image tags, links and all.

I have tried the following in `THEME_preprocess_node`, but it results in a short trimmed version as it counts the html as characters -> trims to 200 -> removes tags:

```
if(isset($variables['content']['body'][0]['#markup']) && $variables['teaser']) {
    $variables['content']['body'][0]['#markup'] = strip_tags($variables['content']['body'][0]['#markup'], '<p> <br>');
}
```

This seems like surprising behavior, is trimmed not normally clean? PS this should ideally not be done in the template file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Smart Trim](https://drupal.org/project/smart_trim) module. It gives all sorts of options for customizing trim functionality, including stripping HTML.

Comment: Nice module. Unfortunately the module description states: Note that HTML markup not seen by end-users will still be counted when calculating trim length. This may be addressed in future releases. This is exactly what OP wants to solve.

Comment: "_Note that HTML markup not seen by end-users will still be counted when calculating trim length. This may be addressed in future releases._" Even though the module page says this, the module does actually trim after stripping HTML. Some other cool options in there too, COOL!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) or [hook_node_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) and render the teaser the way you want it.

Comment: So make a module, apply hooks override teaser output, all seems a bit much for this. It feels like it should be in the display options for a text field. Thanks for the suggestion